# C# Collision Check for PictureBox (Intersect)

Tags: c#, game-physics

I've been challenging with this problem for a long time. Simply, I want to avoid the collision between two pictureboxes. pictureBox1 has to stop when it sees the pictureBox2. However, I did manage to do that with Intersect. Like the code down below;

```
 private void method(PictureBox b)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(b.Bounds)) {
            movement = false;}                                         
    }
```

The problem is Keypress. I'm moving pictureBox1 with KeyDown(W, A, S, D) and when I hold down the keys, intersect code works perfectly fine. But when I press to keys one by one, it just slides into pictureBox2. How can I avoid this? I did try to stop it with boolean but it didn't work. I guess I need if statements but I just can't make the logic. Looking for your solutions. Thanks in advance.

KeyDown event;

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (movement == true)
        {
            int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
            int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= chrspeed;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= chrspeed;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += chrspeed;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += chrspeed;

            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
            method(pictureBox2);

        }


    }
```

chrspeed is 20;

KeyUp event;

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        movement = true;


    }
```

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. `method` is actually a bad name for a method.

Comment: Please show your 'keypress' methods and more relevant stuff (the code you have shown doesn't help much).

Comment: Keypress event is empty. I thought the problem is somehow connected with the KeyPress event, that's why I mentioned. @PoulBak

Comment: You are in luck that it is one-by-one stepping that fails. Move your rectangles close together and then set a breakpoint and start debugging. You might not get the events you are expecting.

Comment: Method is just for clarifying. You can call it collisioncheck if you want. It was originally CLcheck.

Comment: I meant 'Keydown', since that is what you use.

Comment: Didn't work @LosManos

Comment: Added and those are all the codes @PoulBak

Comment: How does movement become true?

Comment: İn the KeyUp  event.@LarsTech

Comment: Follow the logic: press down, nothing, because movement is false.  Let go, movement is true.  Press down, move stuff because movement is true, if collide, movement is false.  But let go, movement is true again.  movement is never false when you press the keys one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened in your code and "worked"(it didn't, you were lucky) was, the first time the two picboxes intersected, picbox1 moved in picbox2, `method` returned `false` and the next time it didn't enter the `if` statement.
You need to call `method()` **before** moving picbox1 and **then** check for `true or false`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
    int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= chrspeed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= chrspeed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += chrspeed;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += chrspeed;

    method(new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height), pictureBox2 );

    if (movement == true)
    {
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }

}
```

and

```
private void method(Rectangle rect, PictureBox b)
{
    if (rect.IntersectsWith(b.Bounds)) {
        movement = false;}                                         
}
```

Comment: Well, it stopped moving after collision.

Comment: I'll try this wait a sec please.

Comment: We are looking to a genious guys. Thank you so much bro. <3

Answer (score 0):

I would make this into the KeyDown eventhandler and delete the KeyUp eventhandler. The problem with your code is, that every time you release a key, *the `movement` flag gets reset to true.*
This should do what you want:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                int x = pictureBox1.Location.X;
                int y = pictureBox1.Location.Y;

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W) y -= chrspeed;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x -= chrspeed;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x += chrspeed;
                else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) y += chrspeed;

                Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(x, y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                if (!newRect.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds)) {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
```

No need for `movement` flag. What it does is that it sets the new location, if the two pictureboxes don't intersect.

Note that when pictureboxes collide, you can still press another key to move away again.

`Edit`:

Your comment is absolutely correct, sorry for that.
I have now changed the code, so it uses the new position to calculate whether they intersect.

Comment: I tried it and when they collide, it stopped moving. It doesn't move away since it's collided already.